# I can't bind additional parameters to AngularJS call

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have ASP.NET application with the form handled by AngularJS. There are 2 date-time pickers (fromDate and toDate variables) and check box that indicate if open dates are included (isOpenDatesIncluded).

The code looks as following:

1) In first AngularJS module:

```
SearchActionsApp.controller("ListController", function($scope, $location,$q, Actions, ActionDates, CounterAgents,Counteragents, AsyncTask) {
...

$scope.actionsQuery = {
    searchText: "",
    fromDate: new Date(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY")),
    toDate: new Date(moment().add('d', 3).format("MM/DD/YYYY")),
    isOpenDatesIncluded: false,
...

ActionDates.query({ actionId: action.Id, isOpenDatesIncluded: $scope.actionsQuery.isOpenDatesIncluded, fromDate: $scope.actionsQuery.fromDate, toDate: $scope.actionsQuery.toDate }, task.success, task.error);

...

}
```

2) In service.js:

```
.factory('ActionDates', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/RestApi/api/ActionDates', {});
})
```

3) On server side:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<ActionDateItem> GetByQuery([FromUri]ActionDateQuery query)
{
    return _service.QueryActionDates(query);
}

public IEnumerable<ActionDateItem> QueryActionDates(ActionDateQuery query)
{
    var sql = query.BuildSql();
    using (var cn = CreateSqlConnection())
    {
        return cn.Query<ActionDateItem>(sql, new
        {
            query.ActionId,
            query.IsOpenDatesIncluded,
            BeginDate = query.FromDate,
            EndDate = query.ToDate
        });
    }
}

public class ActionDateQuery
{
    public ActionDateQuery()
    {
        ActionId = -1;
        IsOpenDatesIncluded = false;
        FromDate = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1);
        ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }

    public long ActionId { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpenDatesIncluded { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is the query returns the set of data from: 1980, 1, 1 to DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), but I need to return the data in range: fromDate - toDate, which I get from the client side.

The parameters from client side attached to RestApi URL are correct, but I only get the first parameter - ActionId on server side. I don't get 3 others - IsOpenDatesIncluded, FromDate and ToDate.

I'm not sure how to bind them in service.js file.

How to do that?

Comment: Try : For GET method use [FromUri]. For POST method use [FromBody] like below    public IEnumerable<ActionDateItem> QueryActionDates([FromUri]ActionDateQuery query)

Comment: I already have it. Please, take a look at the original post that I've just edited.

Comment: Please share a code where you are making $http.get

Comment: There's no $http.get. We use $resource.